# AutomaticHelper process + High CPU usage

Tags: macos, process

I can't find any info on an OSX process named AutomaticHelper.

What is it?

Why does it like to chew through CPU so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's part of [Automatic](http://codingcurious.com/automatic/), which is used for RSS-based downloading.

Comment: makes perfect sense. It's a shame the damn app is so CPU hungry. Must be a bug.

thank you.